# Начиная с какой версии XCode поддерживается разработка виджетов для рабочего стола IPhone?

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, виджет

Я совсем новичек в IOs разработке и оцениваю возможности платформы пока-что. Писал виджеты для Android. Для разработки виджетов какая версия XCode минимальная? подойдет XCode 10.3 macOS 10.14.6? Слышал что это в бете XCode 11.4 только... и соответственно MacOS тоже надо обновлять что плохо для меня:)  И можно мануал по разработке простенького виджета на рабочий стол IPhone - сам не нашел пока нормального мануала.
Вот список версий XCode:
(XCode 11.4.1) -   macOS Catalina 10.15.4
(XCode 11.4; XCode 11.3.1; XCode 11.3) -   macOS Catalina 10.15.2
(XCode 11.2.1; XCode 11.2; XCode 11.1; XCode 11)  -   macOS Catalina 10.15 
(XCode 10.3)    -   macOS 10.14.6
(XCode 10.2)    -   macOS 10.14.4
(XCode 10.1)    -   macOS 10.14.1
(XCode 10)  -   macOS 10.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из [этой статьи](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-your-first-widget-in-ios-14-with-widgetkit-9b893423e815) нужно минимум `Xcode 12.0 beta 1 or above`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо можно подождать апдейта. [Вот есть документация](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension) по вашему вопросу и [статья](https://www.raywenderlich.com/11303363-getting-started-with-widgets) а в [этой статье](https://habr.com/ru/company/cardsmobile/blog/519516/) говорилось о `Xcode 12 beta 6`.

### UPDATE

Спасибо [@schmidt9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204219/schmidt9) немного тупанул)) Уже есть возможность создавать виджеты, так как последняя версия стабильная ( у меня на ноуте во всяком случае) стоит `Version 12.2 (12B45b)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылки

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Comment: @Andrew `ждать стабильной версии или бету ставить` - уже есть стабильный релиз XCode 12.1

Comment: @schmidt9, спасибо большое за замечание)) тупанул немного)) совсем недавно у себя обновлял но забыл уже :( возраст все-таки :D